# Hello world in haskell

Tags: haskell

This code is from a tutorial online that didn't really explain the logic behind this haskell code that prints "Hello, World". Could you explain what exactly is going on here. I'm particularly confused about what is going on in the last line and how it makes greet = Hello. Why is "who" needed? What is it's significance? And why is greet not just set as "hello". What am I supposed to learn out of this code snippet? Please forgive me as I am just getting into the world of functional programming and I think something obvious just flew over my head.

```
main :: IO () 

main = putStrLn (greet "World") 

greet who = "Hello, " ++ who
```

Comment: It’s an example program showing off a function `greet` that takes a name and returns a new string greeting the name. Sure you could make it a simple string value instead of a function with `greet = "Hello, World"` and `main = putStrLn greet`, just like you could rewrite the example expression `1 + 1` as `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you if you look at the signature of this function. This is read as the function `greet` takes a `String` and outputs a `String`. The `String` type is just a shorthand for `[Char]`

```
greet :: String -> String
greet who = "Hello, " ++ who
```

is a function which takes one argument `who`. The `++` operator can append two lists and since Strings are Lists of characters in Haskell it will append the lists like this:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' '] ++ ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines of your question it sounds like you are reading

```
(greet "World")
```

as concatenating the string `greet` with the `"World"`. However in Haskell this is how you write function call and its arguments. A language like C or Java would write this as

```
greet ("World")
```

In Haskell brackets are not used for function arguments; instead they are only used for operator priority. "Function application" (meaning calling a function on some arguments) acts like an invisible operator with the highest priority.